# trying to map JObject to c# class using AutoMapper, I'm getting NULL for the child elements

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, automapper

I have the code below everything was working perfectly using AutoMapper v4, but when i upgraded to V8 it starts returning null in the child properties.

The result is now [{"Id":null,"Name":null},{"Id":null,"Name":null}]-TTR0

Anything wrong with my code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AutoMapper;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class WarehouseObj{
    public Warehouse[] Whs { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}

public class Warehouse{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()       
    {
        var jsonString = @"{ 'wareh': [{
        'wid': '1234',
        'wname': 'W0986E'
        },{
        'wid': '1235',
        'wname': 'E0948T'
        }], 'lc' : 'TTR0'}";

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { 
            
            cfg.CreateMap<JObject,WarehouseObj>()
                .ForMember("Whs", opt=>{ opt.MapFrom(jo => jo["wareh"]); })
                .ForMember("Location", opt=>{ opt.MapFrom(jo => jo["lc"]); });  
            
            cfg.CreateMap<JObject, Warehouse>()
                           .ForPath(dest => dest.Id, opt => { opt.MapFrom(src => src["wid"]); })
                           .ForPath(dest => dest.Name, opt => { opt.MapFrom(src => src["wname"]); });
        });
        
        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var jArray = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mapper.Map<WarehouseObj>(jArray).Whs), mapper.Map<WarehouseObj>(jArray).Location);

    }
}
```

Comment: You can see live code here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CGUJdA

Comment: Since you indicated in the comments that my answer help you resolve the problem, please mark it as accepted by ticking the V to its left.

Answer (score 1):

One way of solving such issue is deserializing your json string to concrete classes such as

```
public class Wareh
    {
        public string wid { get; set; }
        public string wname { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<Wareh> wareh { get; set; }
        public string lc { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you can define your maps with statically typed source and destination properties and it will work fine.
For illustration, see the code below.

```
using AutoMapper;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class WarehouseObj
{
    public Warehouse[] Whs { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}

public class Warehouse
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Wareh
{
    public string wid { get; set; }
    public string wname { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Wareh> wareh { get; set; }
    public string lc { get; set; }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var jsonString = @"{ 'wareh': [{
    'wid': '1234',
    'wname': 'W0986E'
    },{
    'wid': '1235',
    'wname': 'E0948T'
    }], 'lc' : 'TTR0'}";

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {

            cfg.CreateMap<Root, WarehouseObj>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Whs, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.wareh))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Location, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.lc));

            cfg.CreateMap<Wareh, Warehouse>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.wid))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.wname));
        });

        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var jArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
        var mapped = mapper.Map<WarehouseObj>(jArray);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mapper.Map<WarehouseObj>(jArray).Whs), mapper.Map<WarehouseObj>(jArray).Location);

    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed it by using OfirD's solution, I can't deserialize it into a class since the original JSON structure is generic.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the second mapping to `JToken` instead of `JObject` works.

So instead of:

```
cfg.CreateMap<JObject, Warehouse>()
```

Use:

```
cfg.CreateMap<JToken, Warehouse>()
```

- Also, note that you can use `ForMember` instead of `ForPath`.

As for the *why*, I'm not really sure. My current guess is that there's some issue with parsing `JArray`'s items into `JObject`s; even if a less complex json is used:

```
var json = @"[{
    'wid': '1234',
    'wname': 'W0986E'
  },{
    'wid': '1235',
    'wname': 'E0948T'
  }]
";
```

the following doesn't work (i.e., it initializes `Warehouse` properties with `null`):

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
   cfg.CreateMap<JObject, Warehouse>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => { opt.MapFrom(src => (string)src["wid"]); })
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => { opt.MapFrom(src => (string)src["wname"]); });
});

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var jArray = JArray.Parse(json);
var des = mapper.Map<Warehouse[]>(jArray);
```

But changing it to use `JToken` will work.

Comment: `ForPath()` offers a much smaller range of options, that is `Condition()`, `Ignore()` and `MapFrom()` while `ForMember()` offers additional transforms, converters, null substitution, precondition and more. Information based on version 10.